# Distinction between function types

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, asymptotics

Hi I'm am currently working on a question on Big O notation and to work out $O(n^k)$ of $f(n)$ you first need to know what type of function $f(n)$ is, polynomial, exponential, logarithmic. My question is does the degree of a function determine what type of function it is?

For example is:

**a)** $67n^3 − 40n^2 + 6n + 3 \log_2 n − 33$ a polynomial function

**b)** $3 \log_2 n − 33$ a logarithmic function

**c)** $2^n + 40n^2 + 6n + 3 \log_2 n$ an exponential function

My specialty is more programming so this isn't too obvious to me :(

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is degree of a function for you in this context?

Comment: high sorry , it's the maximum term in the function as n increases to infinity